# utPLSQL-maven-plugin : UT_COVERAGE_HTML_REPORTER not working for me. (using utPLSQL v 3.1.12)

Tags: oracle, unit-testing, plsql, utplsql

I added the UT_COVERAGE_HTML_REPORTER reporter to the pom.xml, but it does not cover any lines for me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYmlx.png)

Am I doing something wrong?

Added this block to the execution of utplsql-maven-plugin. as shown here: (https://github.com/utPLSQL/utPLSQL-maven-plugin)

```
<reporters>
    <reporter>
        <name>UT_COVERAGE_HTML_REPORTER</name>
        <!-- The file output path. -->
        <fileOutput>report/coverage-html-reporter.html</fileOutput>
        <!-- Indicates if it should write to console. -->
        <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
    </reporter>
</reporters>
```

I thought the default behaviour was that all test packages that are ran are included in the report.
https://www.utplsql.org/utPLSQL/v3.1.12/userguide/coverage.html documentation here.

Could anyone help me out? Thank you very much!